# How to place a div over an HTML5 video?

Tags: css, html, firefox, html5-video

Basically I've made my own custom controls for my web videos, don't wanna use standard controls. Anyway, Now I need to place my control over videos whether the video is in fullscreen mode or not! Based on my googling I found the most recommended way is `z-index:2147483647` This works pretty much with chrome and opera as I've tested it But it does not work in firefox.

```
.video_my{
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
    z-index:1;
}

.my_controls_container{
    position:absolute;
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
    background: white;
    z-index:2147483647; // Also tried !important
}
```

To request for video full screen in Jquery I'm using

```
if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
   vid.requestFullscreen();
} else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
   vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
   vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

And I have created this link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GNaEKL You can try it on firefox and click on that green box and see that the div that should overlay disappears.

So I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me how to place my controls container over the video when video go to full screen mode in firefox?

Comment: When you inspect the page with firefox developer tools do you see any errors? Also might be worth running your code through html and css validators.

Comment: @ovokuro No I can't see no error!

Comment: @ovokuro Can see my question update, and see what is the cause!